# Pushing iOS UIViewController from NSObject class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsobject

I have the following code within my AppDelegate. It is used during checks for In App Purchase expiry, and if a subscription is expiring, will present a popup for the user to choose to renew, and if they do, it will push the view controller for the In App Purchases onto the stack.

I would like to shift the code out of AppDelegate, and into its own NSObject class (just for tidiness). However, how do I call push the View Controller from another class?

`self.window.rootViewController` doesn't exist on the NSObject class, so of course won't function.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
            UICollectionViewController *ivc = (UICollectionViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"IAPViewController"];
            [navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NSObject class, when you want to push a vc, post a notification via NSNotificationCenter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationWithName:@"PushMyViewControllerNote" object:nil];
```

And in AppDelegate.m register observer:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(handlePushVCNotification:)        
                                                 name:@"PushMyViewControllerNote" 
                                               object:nil]; 
    //...
    return YES;
}

//...
- (void)handlePushVCNotification:(NSNotification *)note
{ 
    // First you must find currently visible view controller
    // for how to do it, find it yourself :)
    // but you can check https://gist.github.com/snikch/3661188
    UIViewController *visibleVC = [self findVisibleVC];
    UINavigationController *nc = visibleVC.navigationController;
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UICollectionViewController *ivc = (UICollectionViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"IAPViewController"];
    [nc pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is create a separate class that inherits from NSObject. Call it something like AppPurchase. Then, import your AppPurchase class into your app delegate. As for pushing the view controller, that code should be separate from your AppPurchase class.

The AppPurchase class is part of your Model, and should not be responsible for pushing view controllers around. If data changes in your AppPurchase instance, then the controller can take some action and alter your View.

You should look into learning more about MVC or Model-View-Controller.

Comment: Very good point! And yes, couldn't see the wood for the trees and missed the obvious. Thank you.